# Google Charts only shows one chart per page

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I have two charts i would like to display, but for some reason it only shows the first one

it only shows the sarahChart and if i exchange the order of the functions it will show only the anthonyChart

here is my script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});

    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawSarahChart);

    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawAnthonyChart);

    function drawSarahChart() {

        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Emplacement');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Quantité');
        data.addRows(<?php echo "[\n";
            echo $prefix . " [\n";
            echo '  "Stock",' . "\n";
            echo $count_stock . '' . "\n";
            echo " ]";
            $prefix = ",\n";
            echo $prefix . " [\n";
            echo '  "Maintenance",' . "\n";
            echo $count_maint . '' . "\n";
            echo " ]";
            $prefix = ",\n";
            foreach ( $combined_depart as $key => $value ) {
                echo $prefix . " [\n";
                echo '  "' . $key . '",' . "\n";
                echo $value . '' . "\n";
                echo " ]";
                $prefix = ",\n";
        }
        echo "\n]";?>);

        var options = {title:'Nombre de materiel par emplacement',
                                     width:600,
                                     height:500};

        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('Sarah_chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
    }

    function drawAnthonyChart() {

        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'type');
        data.addColumn('number', 'quantité');
        data.addRows(<?php echo "[\n";
            foreach ( $combined as $key => $value ) {
                echo $prefix . " [\n";
                echo '  "' . $key . '",' . "\n";
                echo $value . '' . "\n";
                echo " ]";
                $prefix = ",\n";
        }
        echo "\n]"; ?>);

        var options = {
            title: "Nombre de materiel par type",
            width: 400,
            height: 300
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('Anthony_chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
    }

</script>
```

and here is the html:

```
<table class="columns">
  <tr>
    <td><div id="Sarah_chart_div"></div></td>
            <td><div id="Anthony_chart_div"></div></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

By the way if i put

```
  google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});

  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawSarahChart);

  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawAnthonyChart);
```

At the start instead, neither of the charts show the console shows the following error:

**Cannot read property 'load' of undefined**

and if i replace only the 2 lines with

```
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawSarahChart);

  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawAnthonyChart);
```

neither show again, the console shows the following error:

**Cannot read property 'setOnLoadCallback' of undefined**

please help, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first `setOnLoadCallback` should only be called once per page

but you can include the `callback` directly in the `load` statement

try something like this...

```
google.load('visualization', '1.0', {
  callback: function () {
    drawSarahChart();
    drawAnthonyChart();
  },
  packages: ['corechart']
});
```

Comment: excuse me i was wrong, it shows only one of the charts and the error says

Every row given must be either null or an array.

Comment: nothing to do with the `load` statement, can you share a sample of the data?

Comment: **data.addRows([,[ "Ecran",4],["Unite centrale",6 ], ["Imprimante",9],["Scanner",4]]);**  here is the line that has the problem as you can see there is an extra comma in the start that my code doesnt have but it shows in the resources when i check the line that has the error in the console

Comment: think you need to initialize the `$prefix` variable before each `foreach`

Comment: i can't believe that was the problem, all is in order now, thank u so much!

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are trying to use same callback twice. Instead of this, you can define a callback function which includes your two sub-function **drawSarahChart** and **drawAnthonyChart**

```
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(function(){
    drawSarahChart();
    drawAnthonyChart();
});
```

Comment: when i tried this it showed neither of the charts with the error
Cannot read property 'setOnLoadCallback' of undefined
and when i removed .charts it still showed only one

Comment: Can you share JSFiddle which includes your final code?